# What is wrong with my Item collection/Itemcounter Script

Tags: unity, javascript, software-engineering

So I am making a script for item collection and a counter for it. I have a script made but for some odd reason I can't seem to the get the GUI part right. The compiler error says something like "This isn't a member of UnityEngineGUI" IDK what I am doing wrong. Could someone help out?

```
#pragma strict
var Collectable : GameObject;
var Counter : int;
var CounterGUI : GUI;

function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider){    
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        Collectable.SetActive(false);
        Counter += 1;
        CounterGUI.GUI = Counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `OnGUI()` in old system.

```
function OnGUI ()
{
    GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), Counter.ToString());
}
```

If you use new UI system, you will need to update the `text` component of the `Text` UI object. No need of `OnGUI()`.

```
CounterTextGUI.text = Counter.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that it's not reacting to the tag of the player. Javascript does it all the time to me. The easiest fix is to have this:
If (other.gameObject.name == "//name of player object in scene//")
{
//rest of code follows...
}